# RSA Encryption and Decryption using 2 files

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, rsa, private-key, public-key

So I have created 2 files one for encryption and other for decryption. I am able to encrypt the text but when it comes to decrypting I get an error (See bottom of question). I am able to export the Private_key.pem, public_key.pem and even the secret.txt file. I am able to read the private_key.pem in my decrypt.py script but it errors out. I believe the script thinks that the private_key it is using is not correct. I know this is wrong as I generate the public and private key, use the public key to encrypt and private to decrypt. If anyone can shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Encrypt.py

```
from Crypto import Cipher
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

from Crypto.PublicKey.pubkey import pubkey

def privKEY():
    private_key = RSA.generate(4096)
    return private_key

def pubKey():
    public_Key = privKEY().publickey()
    return public_Key

def convertPrivKey():
    private_pem = privKEY().exportKey().decode()
    with open('private_pem.pem','w') as pr:
        pr.write(private_pem)
    return private_pem

def convertPubKey():
    public_pem = pubKey().exportKey().decode()
    with open('public_pem.pem','w') as pu:
        pu.write(public_pem)
    return public_pem

def encrypt():
    privKEY()
    pubKey()
    convertPrivKey()
    convertPubKey()
    message = 'Testing RSA Encryption'
    message = message.encode()
    pu_key = RSA.importKey(open('public_pem.pem','r').read())
    print(pu_key)
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pu_key)
    cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(message)
    with open('secret.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(str(cipher_text))
encrypt()
```

decrypt.py

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def load_secure_file():
    return open('secret.txt','r').read()

def pr_key_read():
    pr_key = RSA.importKey(open('private_pem.pem','r').read())
    return pr_key

def decrypt():
    encrypted_text = load_secure_file()
    pr_key = pr_key_read()
    decrypt = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pr_key)
    decrypted_message = decrypt.decrypt(encrypted_text)
    return decrypted_message
decrypt()
```

ERROR:

```
PS Y:\Python\RSA> & C:/Anaconda/python.exe y:/Python/RSA/decrypt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y:/Python/RSA/decrypt.py", line 19, in <module>
    decrypt()
  File "y:/Python/RSA/decrypt.py", line 17, in decrypt
    decrypted_message = decrypt.decrypt(encrypted_text)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 195, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length.")
ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.
```

New Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y:/Python/RSA/decrypt.py", line 19, in <module>
    decrypt()
  File "y:/Python/RSA/decrypt.py", line 14, in decrypt
    encrypted_text = load_secure_file()
  File "y:/Python/RSA/decrypt.py", line 7, in load_secure_file
    return open('secret.txt','r').read()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 30: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: No it doesn't "think the private kay is incorrect". It says right there: "Ciphertext with incorrect length". That's because you convert the encrypted value to string, but encrypted values are arbitrary bits (Python `bytes`) and not valid characters, so converting to string corrupts and destroys your data, and so may reading as text (which is the default). **Use Python's binary I/O.** Also you should be aware using RSA directly to encrypt data is very limited and (thus) rarely used; in your case the limit is about 200 bytes, which may be as little as 50 chars or even less.

Comment: as what @dave_thompson_085 said you should open the secrets.txt file in binary mode not utf-8 string mode.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I updated the output of secret.txt to 'wb' and now I am getting this new error.

Comment: It seems you'll have to do the opposite of `str()` on the decrypt side.

Comment: An additional problem is that the keys used in encryption and decryption do not belong together, s. `encrypt()`: `convertPrivKey()` generates a private key `Priv1` and stores it. `convertPubKey()` also generates a private key `Priv2` (in the `pubKey()` call) and stores the _associated_ public key `Pub2`. So the stored keys `Priv1` and `Pub2` do not belong together, but are used later for encryption and decryption.

Comment: After switching to binary mode (`wb`, `rb`) for writing _and_ reading concerning _secret.txt_ the `str()` call must also be removed (actually a runtime error should happen with `str()`).

Answer (score 1):

Topaco is right: you're actually generating *four* keypairs, throwing away the first two, writing the private key from the third and the public key from the fourth. These keys don't match and thus don't work. You should generate *one* keypair and use the private and public halves of *that* pair. The following slightly simplified code works for me:

```
from Crypto import Cipher
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# privKEY,pubKey
private_key = RSA.generate(2048) # shortened for testing
public_key = private_key.publickey()
# 'convert' really store
with open('private.pem','w') as pr:
  pr.write(private_key.exportKey().decode())
with open('public.pem','w') as pu:
  pu.write(public_key.exportKey().decode())

# encrypt
message = 'Testing RSA'.encode()
pu_key = RSA.importKey(open('public.pem','r').read())
ciphertext = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pu_key).encrypt(message)
with open('secret.txt','wb') as f:
  f.write(ciphertext)

# decrypt
ciphertext = open('secret.txt','rb').read()
pr_key = RSA.importKey(open('private.pem','r').read())
decrypted = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pr_key).decrypt(ciphertext)
print(decrypted)

-->
b'Testing RSA'
```

The caveat that this only works for limited amount of data remains.

Comment: Oh my god...now this works. Thank you very much for your help.